# function new or public static main

Tags: constructor, haxe

I am new to Haxe and probably this is a pretty basic question, which I can't really find an answer.

I see three ways to call main class:

1) use main()

```
//Entry point
public static main():void{
   //do something...
}
```

2) use constructor new()

```
//Constructor
public function new(){
   // init
}
```

3) use both main() and new()

```
static function main()
{
    Lib.window.onload = function(e) new Main();
}

public function new()
{
   //init
}
```

Is there a guideline or best practice to which one to use?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Addressing all 3:

1. **static function main() {}** is the correct entry point.  No matter which target, Haxe always begins execution at main().
2. The **new()** constructor isn't called automatically, if you want your main app to execute as an object rather than from a static function, you have to explicitly create the object: `static function main() { new Main(); }`
3. Some people prefer to keep their code in an object, rather than in static functions, which is where your 3rd example comes from.  I usually do, and that's what you show in your 3rd example.

A few extra points:

- The steps things are executed is explained [here](http://haxe.org/doc/advanced/magic#initialization-magic), basic summary:

  - All types/classes are registered
  - `Boot.__init()` runs platform specific initializations
  - Classes which have `static function __init__()` initialization methods are initialized
  - Static variables are intiailzed
  - Your `main()` function is executed
- If you compile a class without a `-main Main` argument, but with the class path/name as an argument (eg `haxe my.pack.MyClass`) and with no `public static function main()`, the class is compiled, but it is not run automatically.  This can be useful if you are creating a library or something similar - your class is there, but it needs to be called explicitly by some other Javascript etc.
- In Javascript, the Haxe code starts running as soon as it is loaded, possibly before the DOM is ready.  That is why it is a good idea to do:

  ```
  static function main() {
    js.Lib.window.onload = function(e) { runMyApp(); }
  }
  ```

  As you did in your example, this is a good idea if you want your code to run *after* the DOM is ready.  Whether on load you call another static function, or instantiate a `new MyApp()` and run your app from there, that is up to you.

Comment: A remark about your 2nd extra point : the haxe compiler refuses to compile when you omit the -main argument.  It also refuses to compile with a main function that doesn't define a static main function.

Comment: @xastor If you insert the class name (including the full package path) it works.  I'll edit my answer to include that.  Thanks :)

Comment: Sweet!  Byebye main stub :)